# C# - write to multiple files

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, file-io, task-parallel-library

I am currently using File.WriteAllLines method to create two text files from a string array in a .Net Console Application.

```
 string[] data = {"Apple", "Orange", "Lemon", ...};
 File.WriteAllLines("1.txt", data.OrderBy(d=>d));
 File.WriteAllLines("2.txt", data.OrderByDescending(d=>d));
```

The array is huge so it takes some time to create both files. Should I create tasks to improve the performance. Example:

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => File.WriteAllLines("1.txt", data.OrderBy(d=>d)));
var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => File.WriteAllLines("2.txt", data.OrderByDescending(d=>d));
Task.WaitAll(t1,t2);
```

The alternate option is to use WriteAsync method.

What is the best practice around this? Is it worth parallelising file write operation?

Comment: In the words of Eric Lippert - [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: It's not usually worth parallelising I/O-bound operations like that - if you were writing the files to a normal hard drive, that could make things slower overall as the heads are forced to seek between the two regions being written to. (This isn't so much of an issue for SSD storage of course).

Comment: There are too many unknowns here. You will need to test it yourself and evaluate. If, for instance, the bottleneck is the disc, then no amount of CPU-level parallelization will improve performance, more likely to hurt it.

Comment: Why don't you see if writing one file, then copying to another performs better?

Comment: You will need to play with the write buffer of file stream to make this more efficient, 4k is extremely small for SSD's

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have SSD but the deployment server does not have SSD so it will not give realist idea hence looking for the best practice around this.

Comment: Best practice is to use a benchmarking solution on your deployment environment, and play with the buffer / sequential writes sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, parallelism doesn't work well with IO resources.  Even the fastest SSD is waaaay slower than any CPU out there.  Whether you spawn tasks or not, the disk will be your bottleneck.  But, you have also disk cache, you have other processes fighting for you disk.

You need to test. But, even if it works better in a single case, it is not guaranteed it will be always like that.

When it comes to reading and writing on disk, I will personally avoid spawning tasks.